# Linux Mint Startup error due to insufficient disk space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, memory-usage, linuxmint

Can you help me please to solve this issue?

I am on Linux Mint 18.3. I use it for java script development.
I have just Chrome, node and Visual Studio Code.

Just couple days ago disk analyzer told me, that is not enough of disk space.
I tried to delete (permanently) files, but free space wasnt updated.
On my last successful startup I got lots of erros, that I couldnt even load any application due to insufficient memory space on hard drive .
Now I even couldnt enter into the system - after successful login, I am redirected again to the login form. Guest option - the same result.
All of recovery options I launched.

Help me please solve it!

Comment: Morning!

I found an answer to clean my cache inside /var/cache/archive *.deb files
But my /var/cache contains only folder /fontconfig and /ldconfig

After I am running recovery mode in Mint, its shows me first error after this:

Comment: `Begin: Will now check root file system ... fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/sda5] fsck.ext4 -a -CO /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5 contains file system with errors, check forced.
[   10.803397] random: crng init done                     | 0.3%
/dev/sda5:
Extended attribute block 2740536 has reference account 6, should be 5.`

Comment: `/dev/sd5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
fsck exited with status code 4
done.
Failture: File system check of the root filesystem failed
The root filesystem on /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck
[   36.975860] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[   36.975860] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   36.975860] usbhid: USB HID core driver



BusyBox v 1.22.1 (Ubuntu......`

Comment: .....here cli runs
**If its a problem with a disk space, what can I delete to clean it?** 
As I said before, I suppose that the problem is about disk space, I am not sure here.

ls command from root folder initial this
`dev   scripts   sbin   etc    run   bin   lib   proc
root  var       usr    lib64  conf  init  sys   tmp `

Comment: In linux cli I have limited capabilities of commands and I coudnt see all folders, for example /home or some folders inside others.
Using Disk Internals (Windows tool to get linux files), I can see everything. **I mean that files arent corrupted.**